# start evolution with threads collapsed?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, xfce, evolution

For working in linux I can use evolution to access email from all 'corporate' server types: Outlook, Exchange, etc which is great. Often though with new e-mails in long threads, the only thing I see is the first thread. I get a much better view when I do View -> Collapse All Threads. Is it possible to do this by default?

[This page](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1148978) seems to suggest that it can be set with `gsettings get [or set] org.gnome.evolution.mail thread-expand` but that seems to work only in 1 direction, *i.e.*, force expanding not collapsing?

Answer (score 5):

On my Ubuntu 18 this command did the trick (by default, thread-expand is true)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.evolution.mail thread-expand false
```